# Redirect to login page in production on a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to programtically reroute all my request to the login page in production on a Rails app, while keeping access to the other anonymous access pages in development.

For example if I have a request for www.mywebsite.com/listings I want to show them up in development but to redirect it to the login page in production with the main purpose to keep my app in stealth mode until is release.

Is there a best well-know way to do this, because I think is a very common problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application controller...

```
before_filter :stealth_mode

def stealth_mode
    redirect_to login_url if Rails.env.production?
end
```

And in your login controller

```
skip_before_filter :stealth_mode
```

And here your go! :-)

Answer (score 1):

in your routes:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  match '(:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format))))' => "root_controller#root_action"
else
  #your routes declarations
end

root :to => "root_controller#root_action"
```

Comment: That helps me a lot! I was kind of afraid if the routes file will look a little bit dirty if I start mixing logic for different environments, but I think it should be fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: just beware of rails: it will complain if you link to pages with unknown path in your views (basically, your root page should not contain any `link_to`. @christianblais answer is better for this reason. At least, you can add conditions in your routes.rb file

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will consider @christianblais too!, and thanks for the rapid responses, I'm very surprise of how SO feels like chating sometimes...